# Let $U, V \in M_{n\times n}$ be orthogonal matrices. Explain why $UV$ is an orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

So I think this has something to do with $UV$ being invertible and then its inverse would be the transpose of $UV$ but I'm not exactly sure how to explain this properly on an exam.

Comment: what is $(UV)(UV)^t$?

Comment: If $T=UV$, what is $T^{-1}$?

Comment: Your thoughts are exactly correct, why not try it out. Recall, $(UV)^T=V^TU^T$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inverse of $UV$ is its transpose because $(UV)^{-1} = V^{-1}U^{-1} = V^TU^T = (UV)^T$. So it is an orthogonal matrix.

Comment: $(UV)^{-1}=V^{-1}U^{-1}$ and $(UV)^T=V^TU^T$.

Comment: ops, that's correct, fixed it

Comment: Aren't you assuming that UV has an inverse here?

Comment: If $U$ and $V$ have inverses then $(UV)^{-1} = V^{-1}U^{-1}$, you should check this.